# decode embedded parameter in filename string in php

Tags: php, hyperlink, echo

I have a short piece of code which someone wrote for my website, but he failed to complete the job.  I'm rusty on HTML, (let alone PHP), so please treat me gently.  I'm going to try to fix this problem myself.

This is the code as it stands:

```
      <div class="sliderthumb-text">
        <p><?php echo $name[0]; ?></p>
        <p>Born <?php echo $name[1]; ?></p>
        <p><?php echo mb_strtoupper($name[2]); ?></p>
        <p>Blonde</p>
        <p>Age at shoot: <?php echo substr($name[4],0,2); ?></p>
      </div>
```

There's two things missing.

Blonde should not be hardcoded.  It should be an IF THEN ELSE ELSE ... with five parameters drawn from name(3) within a filename.  The filename of the series of images in the slider is in the format *name(0)_name(1)_name(2)_name(3)_name(4).jpg* where *name(3)* is a single digit number indicating hair colour.  So

1. Blonde
2. Brunette
3. Black
4. Redhead
5. Coloured

The second problem is that *?php echo $name[0]; ?* should contain a hyperlink to another page called *filename.php* with a parameter containing name(0).  Now as I say I'm no PHP programmer, so I am assuming that the parameter should be shown as *filename.php?name(0)*

If I'm wrong, please explain what I should do.

Sorry to sound a bit stupid.  I haven't written code at this level since ASP back in 2001.  Hence the reason I am very rusty.  Can anyone help me please?

Thank you.

Comment: You should not start coding complex conditionals in there. Instead use some preparation step where you collect all tokens you need into an associative array (or an object) and then use a separate file holding your html markup (the "view") and fill that with the contents of that array. That way your code stays readable and logical.

Comment: @arkascha OK.  Thank you.  I understand the principal of what you are saying.  But I would not have a clue where to look to start trying to implement it.

Comment: Is my associated array answer her please? https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said blonde should not be hardcoded but you should not have hardcoded parameters such as:

```
<?php echo $name[1]; ?>
```

However if you are after a quick fix the array seems to have $name[1] and the way to four. I have seen that number 3 is missing so I don't want to assume but try coding in

```
<p><?php echo $name[3]; ?></p>
```

That should in theory bring up the value required if he set it up properly. If not try and see where the information is coming from by doing this:

```
<?php print_r($name); ?>
```

That will show all of the values of the array and you can see which values you will need

Comment: thank you.  I'll try that first.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: OK.  So far I can display 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5, but what I want to display is Blonde, Brunette, Black, Redhead and Coloured.

Comment: Now I could rename all the JPG files (several hundred of them), and use Blonde etc instead of 1 etc, but I'm sure there has to be a way of getting the number from the filename and displaying the hair colour rather than the number.  (Sorry if I'm sounding really stupid.  I'm not a programmer.  I'm a photographer.)

Comment: Well the images need to be stored somewhere, do you have them stored anywhere?

Comment: Yes the images are all on my server in /directoryname/

Comment: My problem is how to have "Blonde" appear on screen instead of "1" and so on in name(3)

Comment: Well, if it's coming up as one it's returning as a boolean meaning that the value is either there or it isn't. So you're looking for the name to print out I'm assuming?

Comment: Yes that's correct.  I presume I have to declare an array: 0 = option a, 1 = option b and so on to 4.

Comment: Success.  Worked out a solution with a little help from a friend here based on information above.  Thank you everyone.

Comment: You'll have to show me the results haha :) @BarneyDouglas

Comment: <div class="sliderthumb-text">
            <p><a href="<?php echo 'target.php?      parameter='.urlencode($name[0]); ?>"><?php echo     $name[0]; ?></a></p>  
            <p>Born <?php echo $name[1]; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo mb_strtoupper($name[2]); ?></p>
            <?php
   $hairColor = array("none", "Blonde", "Brunette",     "Black", "Redhead", "Other");
   ?>
   <p><?php echo $hairColor[$name[3]]; ?></p>
            <p>Age: <?php echo substr($name[4],0,2); ?>     </p>
          </div>

Comment: @BarneyDouglas Don't forget to flag this as an answer :) just so no one else comes across this question and wastes their time answering haha :)

Comment: Not sure how to do that?

Comment: @BarneyDouglas you click the tick underneath the answer :)